# Environment.WorkingSet incorrectly reports memory usage

Tags: asp.net, memory-management

Environment.WorkingSet incorrectly reports the memory usage for a web site that runs on Windows 2003 Server.(OS Vers: Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2, .NET Vers: 2.0.50727.3607)

It reports memory as Working Set(Physical Mem.): 1952 MB (2047468061).

Same web site runs locally on Windows Vista with a Working Set(Physical Mem.): 49 MB (51924992).

I have limited access to the server and support is so limited :(.
so i have computed the total memory by traversing with VirtualQuery.
Total of pages with state: MEM_FREE is 1300 MB.
(I guess server have 4 GBs of RAM and PAE is not enabled, max user mode virtual address is 0x7fff0000.)

So, i know working set is not only about virtual memory. But, is it normal to have such a high working set while its very low on another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related to what is described in [this article](http://www.chrisbrandsma.com/2005/05/fun-with-workingset-and-int32.html):

> MAY 04, 2005
>   **Fun with the WorkingSet and int32**
>   I finally found an honest to goodness bug in the .NET framework.
>
> ... the
>   WorkingSet returns the amount of memory being used by the process as
>   an integer (32 bit signed integer). OK, so the maximum value of an
>   integer is 2,147,483,647 -- which is remarkably close to the total
>   amount of memory that a process can have in its working set.
>
> ... There is actually a switch in Windows that will allow a process to use
>   3 gig of memory instead of 2 gig. This switch is often turned on when
>   dealing with Analysis Services -- this thing can be a memory hog. So
>   now what happens is that when I poll the WorkingSet I get a negative
>   number, a really big negative number. Usually, in the realm of
>   -2,147,482,342.
>
> ... The problem was the overflow bit.
>
> Working set is returned to the .NET framework as a binary value. The
>   first bit of an integer is the sign bit. 0 is positive, 1 is negative.
>   So, when the value turned from (binary)
>   1111111111111111111111111111111 to (binary)
>   10000000000000000000000000000000 the value goes from 2147483647 to
>   -2147483647.
>
> OK, so I still have to fix this. Here is what I came up with (in C#):
>
> ```
> long lWorkingSet = 0;
> if (process.WorkingSet >= 0)
>  lWorkingSet = processWorkingSet;
> else
>  lWorkingSet = ((long)int.MaxValue*2)+process.WorkingSet;
> ```
>
> Hopefully that fixes the problem for now.
>
> The real question will come in down the road. Microsoft [knows](http://web.archive.org/web/20070214002249/http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2003/10/16/50535.aspx) about
>   this problem. I still have find out how they are going to fix this for
>   Win64...where this trick will no longer work.

---

> http://msdn2.microsoft.com/library/0aayt1d0(en-us,vs.80).aspx:
>   There's gonna be a Process.WorkingSet64 variable, and they're
>   deprecating WorkingSet.
>
> On a tangent, though, I thought it was impossible for a managed
>   process to come near the 3gb limit, because the runtime splits the
>   memory into multiple heaps. Is this not true?

Comment: It's a shame this answer was a link only.  The link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, `Environment.WorkingSet` is probably returning the value from `GetProcessWorkingSetSize`, which is basically what has been set with `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`. It's basically whatever the system has picked as the largest working set size it would *like* to see for this process, not necessarily anything to do with how much memory it's actually using. The basic effect is that when/if the process uses more memory than that, the system's working set trimmer goes to work seeing if it can get some of its memory paged out to disk.

Comment: no, it is not using GetProcessWorkingSetSize, it uses GetProcessMemoryInfo() from psapi.dll to access process memory counter value, WorkingSetSize.